# Replace anchor tag using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, str-replace, replaceall

```
"TEST START<a class=\"fic.test\" testexpression=\"LTRIM(a)\" testognlexpression=\"${LTRIM(a)}\" href=\"\">a</a>TEST END";
```

I am having anchor tag in String variable. i want to retrieve only value of attr testognlexpression.

Abouve string should be replaced with this

```
TEST START ${LTRIM(a)} TEST END
```

how can i retrieve or replace?

my code looks like

```
String text = "START<a class=\"fic.test\" testexpression=\"LTRIM(a)\" testognlexpression=\"${LTRIM(a)}\" href=\"\">a</a>END";
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll( "</?a[^>testognlexpression]*>", "" ));
}
```

Comment: And again... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = (text.replaceAll( "(?i)(<a[^>]*?\\stestexpression\\s*)=\"", "" ));
        return text.replaceAll("}\"\\shref.+</a>", "}");
```

But still looking for 1 line solution .

Answer (score 1):

```
       public static void main(String []args){
       String text = "<a class=\"fic.test\" testexpression=\"LTRIM(a)\" testognlexpression=\"${LTRIM(a)}\" href=\"\">a</a>";
       String val=text.replaceAll( ".*testognlexpression=", "" );
       System.out.println(val.split("\\s+")[0].replaceAll("\"",""));
       }
```

OP :

```
${LTRIM(a)}
```

Comment: Updated the question :)                                                "TEST START<a class=\"fic.test\" testexpression=\"LTRIM(a)\" testognlexpression=\"${LTRIM(a)}\" href=\"\">a</a>TEST END";

Comment: Not working for me :(                                                 String text = "TEST <a class=\"fic.test\" testexpression=\"LTRIM(a)\" testognlexpression=\"${LTRIM(a)}\" href=\"\">a</a>END";
  String text1 = text.replaceAll("*.</a>","");
  String text2 = text.replaceAll("\"","");
  System.out.println(text1+text2);